# Get Desktop Configuration File to run 2 programs when clicked

Tags: unity-2d

How do I get a Desktop Configuration File to start two programs when clicked, with one of the programs being a terminal program?

Here is what I have so far: [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13w0NTm9POQeWKxYOLGpdmZbwX7LBDbYjq0CprxvmNAo/edit?hl=en_US)

This link will let you edit the file if there's anything that needs to be changed to make it work.

`irssi` is the terminal program. I think you all know what `firefox` is.

Now I can't get the irssi command in the TWiT Live! Chat shortcut to work.

Comment: Can someone edit the file to make the irssi command work for the [Chat Shortcut Group]?

Comment: I show you how to do in my answer? Have you read it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `Exec` line like this:

```
Exec=sh -c 'firefox & gnome-terminal -x irssi'
```